# Moving all values from table1 to table2( with 1 new column)

Tags: android, sqlite

Am copying alll values from **Table1** to **Table2**.

**Note** : In Table2 i have added extra one column at last position.

**Table1** has 16 columns
**Table2** has 17 columns.

I used the following query :

```
String s = "INSERT INTO customer_profile_details SELECT * FROM customer_profile";
db.execSQL(s);
```

It throws the exception as :

```
03-11 06:34:46.383: E/Copy table(24750):  Failed to copy table
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table customer_profile_details has 17 columns but 16 values were supplied (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO customer_profile_details SELECT * FROM customer_profile
```

How to solve this, i need to pass empty value to new column.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String s = "INSERT INTO customer_profile_details SELECT cp.*, null FROM customer_profile cp";
db.execSQL(s);
```

Comment: Navjot Singh : Working fine.Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT INTO** customer_profile_details (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4 ... CoL17)
    **SELECT** COL1, COL2, COL3, ... Col16 , **"constant valid default value for 17 column or null if permitted"**
    **FROM** customer_profile;

Also it's better to have a default value constraint for the column 17 in table structure itself , to better handle the miss-leading